# Objective-C Remove extra parentheses inside NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this Mutable array that has this value

```
myArray = (
        (
        "1466759705.37136"
    ),
        (
        "1466761980.81194"
    ),
        (
        "1466990587.45011"
    )
```

I want to remove the () on each element inside the array and make it like this

```
innerArrayOfDate = (
        "1466759705.37136",

        "1466761980.81194",

        "1466990587.45011"
    )
```

I tried myArray[0] to see if I will not include the parentheses but it still includes.

```
myArray[0] = (
        "1466759705.37136"
    )
```

Comment: What you had written to create this array?

Comment: Try this: `myArray[0][0]`

Comment: @BhavinRamani you saved me a lot of time thanks man.

Comment: welcome @JaysonOng :)

Comment: This is array of array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have array value which is inside of another array.

The value which you want is at 0 index of array so, you need to just add this `myArray[0][0]` instead of this `myArray[0]`

---

```
myArray[0] = (
        "1466759705.37136"
    )
```

---

```
myArray[0][0] = "1466759705.37136"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@[@"1466759705.37136"],@[@"1466761980.81194"],@[@"1466990587.45011"]];
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSArray *array in myArray) {
        [newArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
    }
```